# How to read file and then make folders based on the names in the file in python

Tags: python-3.x, file, directory, readlines

I'm currently working on a program that reads a given file and then makes folders based on the names in the file. The text file is located in the program directory. When I run my code it gives me this error:
*OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'duck\n'*
It also creates the files, but they are the letters of the first word in the text file rather than all the names. I'm very lost.

This is my code:

```
import os
import sys
my_file = open("new clients.txt", "r")
list = my_file.readlines()
print(list)
for items in list:
    os.mkdir(items)
```

The names within the text file are:

duck
crane
boris
kat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my_file.readlines()` will include the newline character at the end of a line.

I think what you want instead, is the split method.

Simply change `my_file.readlines()` to `my_file.read().split()`, and you should be set.